# Geb cannot see my class as content page

Tags: testing, geb

When i try to run my test i get this Exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Unable to resolve code as content for pages FactIndexPage, or as a property on its Navigator context. Is code a class you forgot to import?
```

Here my test class

```
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import pages.*
import spock.lang.Stepwise

@Stepwise
class FactControllerSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "test de la presence du code dans la page d'acceuil"() {
        given: "test que le champ code de facture est bien present"
        when: 
        to IndexFactPage
        then: $("form", name: code).find("input", type: "button")
    }
}
```

And below the class who describe my page content

import geb.Page

class IndexFactPage extends Page {

```
static url = "/fact/mmapay"
static at = {
     $("h2").text() == "Pour régler votre facture, veuillez saisir:" }

static content = {
    codeField { $("input[name = code]") }
    nomField { $("input[name = nom]") }
    prenomField { $("input[name = prenom]") }
    montantField { $("input[name = montant]") }
    chercher1 { $("input", type: "button") }
    abandonner1 { $("input", type: "button") }      
}
```

}

Please help me to resolve my class IndexFactPage as a content page..

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The part causing you problems is this **$("form", name: code)**.

**$("form", name: "code")** will find you a form named code, this may not be what you're after though based on your page and spec snippets.

Without seeing the page source there's no way to provide a proper solution but here's some observations from your **IndexFactPage**

```
static content = {
    codeField { $("input[name = code]") }
    nomField { $("input[name = nom]") }
    prenomField { $("input[name = prenom]") }
    montantField { $("input[name = montant]") }
    chercher1 { $("input", type: "button") }
    abandonner1 { $("input", type: "button") }      
}
```

These fields **codeField**, **nomField**, **prenomField**, and **montantField** all look like they map to individual fields but **chercher1** and **abandonner1** will select the same button.

Based on what your spec states for it's purpose to be then possibly your spec should look like this -

```
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import pages.*
import spock.lang.Stepwise

@Stepwise
class FactControllerSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "test the presence of the code field on the home page"() {
        when: "we are on the home page"
            to IndexFactPage

        then: "the code field is present"
            codeField.present
    }
}
```